# How can I pass variables between DRY templates and ncludes in Jekyll

Tags: variables, jekyll, dry, liquid

I have a simple Blog site where the front page index is a list of posts, non truncated and rendered exactly like the individual pages.

I have the index page setup and working:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    {% include post/post.html %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Where `post/post.html` contains the post layout using the `post` variable like so:

```
<article>
    <header>
    {% include post/title.html %}
    {% include post/metadata.html %}
  </header>

  <div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
</article>
```

Now, on  a specific post page, I want to reuse this include layout so that I can keep my code DRY, so I have the posts use the `post.html` layout (different from `posts/post.html` above):

```
---
layout: default
comments: true
---
{% include post/post.html %}
```

but the problem is that the include file expects a `post` variable to exist such `post.content` is how you access the content.

I have tried:

```
{% assign post = page %}
```

and that seems to be the right to pass a variable in, but page is not the right one as it renders as a markdown string instead of the html on the page.

So, how can I pass `self` -- or whatever is needed -- so that the include file does not need to be altered for the index page or the post page, thus sharing the same code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @David Jacquel's answer work, I found it to be unclean and a little verbose, though it did get me on the right track.

`_includes/post/post.html` swaps the `{{ post.content }}` for `{{ body }}`

```
<article>
    <header>
    {% include post/title.html %}
    {% include post/metadata.html %}
  </header>

  <div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
    {{ body }}
  </div>
</article>
```

`_layouts/index.html` now uses

```
{% assign body = post.content %}
{% include post/post.html %}
```

`_layouts/post.html` uses:

```
{% assign post = page %}
{% assign body = content %}
{% include post/post.html %}
```

Simple.

Comment: `_layouts/default.html` or `index.html` ?

Comment: You're modifying `_layouts/post.html` but you said that only particular posts need a custom layout.

Comment: I don't think I said that only particular posts need it. I said "rendered exactly like the individual pages" and that I wanted to keep it DRY. This accomplishes that. Thank you for putting me on the right track, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it ! With some layout and variable passing.

Regular post use `post` layout :

```
---
layout: post
....
---
post content ...
```

A custom post use the `custom_post` layout (`_layouts/custom_post.hmtl`)

```
---
layout: custom_post
...
---
post content ...
```

The `_layouts/custom_post.hmtl` layout just calls our post include, passing the `page variable` :

```
---
layout: default
---
{% include post/post.html page=page %}
```

And finally the `_includes/post/post.html` conditionally assign the `post` variable if the `page` variable is set :

```
{% if include.page %}
    {% comment %}
       This only append in the custom_post view context
    {% endcomment %}
    {% assign post = include.page %}
{% endif %}

<article>
    <header>
    {% include post/title.html %}
    {% include post/metadata.html %}
  </header>

  <div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">
    {{ post.content }}
  </div>
</article>
```